# Favorite from a different user in TweetDeck

Tags: tweetdeck

When I hover a tweet and then hover over the "favorite" star, I see "favorite from ", where username is the first user I logged in with. How can I change that, so I can favorite from a different user I've set up? I've tried changing "set as default" username in settings and it doesn't affect it.

Comment: You favourite it from that user, surely?

Comment: Yes, Randolph, that was my question. How do you do that?

Comment: Reopened.  In the absence of explanation, I tend to agree with @paddy:  My best guess is that this was mistaken for a web apps question. In any case, closing a question that isn't a totally obvious call *to the poster* (like spam, wildly unrelated topics, etc.) should come with suggestions or explanations whenever possible.  Sorry for the frustrating experience - closing off-topic questions *is* important to maintaining quality, but can sometimes cause unintended consequences like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the post you want to favorite, then from the "..." drop down menu in the lower right corner chose "Favorite from accounts".

Note that you have to click on/activate the post first to get this menu option.

Comment: Yes, this finally became possible in TweetDeck a couple of months ago :).